# image not updated after upload using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

as the title say, I'm using volley to upload image profile, but my image in not updated after uploaded, even I close and reopen my app it still shows the old image...here's the code

```
final Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) imagePreview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        final String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        StringRequest imageUserReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Config.URL_UPDATE_USER_PROFILE, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                dialog.dismiss();

                try{
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    imageuser.setImageUrl(obj.getString("image"), imageLoader);
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }){

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("image", encodedImage);
                params.put("email", email);

                Log.e(TAG, "Posting params: " + params.toString());
                return params;
            }
        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        imageUserReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(imageUserReq);
```

if I close the app with the back button and open it once more volley loads the old image but if I kill the app it will load the new one, is there any suggestion?

Comment: what is the error u are getting post your log

Comment: try to use progress dialog while uploading image or you can call the same Activity or fragment after uploading.

Comment: there is no error in my log...it just not updated, but if I kill the app it will load the new image...I don't want to use that approach...

Comment: @NikhilSuwalka, it won't change my image if I recall the same fragment, but kill the app does...

Comment: if your are using the adapter then set notifyDataSetChanged(); to adapter because the previous value of imageurl is not changed.

Comment: @NikhilSuwalka I'm not using adapter, just get data from server and set Image in custom NetworkImageView